# JScrollPane - сам меняет свою высоту

Tags: java, height, jscrollpane

https://youtu.be/4wrCXeWwxUk

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемкой само изменяющейся высоты JScrollPane (подробно на видео). Можно ли как нибудь заставить JScrollPane сидеть с одной высотой?

Код создания панели:

```
JPanel serversPane = new JPanel();
serversPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(serversPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JScrollPane serversSPane = new JScrollPane(serversPane);
serversSPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
serversSPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

panel.add(serversSPane);
```

Layout у главной панельки (panel) - `BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)`

Ну и метод добавление элементов в `serversPane`

```
private void addServer(InetAddress ia, String name){
    JPanel serverPanel = new JPanel();
    serverPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,50));
    serverPanel.setSize(new Dimension(400,50));
    serverPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400,50));
    if(last){
        serverPanel.setBackground(new Color(76,99,114));
        last = false;
    }else{
        serverPanel.setBackground(new Color(104,133,152));
        last = true;
    }
    serversPane.add(serverPanel);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JScrollPane нужно присвоить PrefferedSize() с размерами Dimension лучше поэкспериметировать. Вроде начинает работать.
Добавьте в код (например, после создания serversSPane строка 61)такую строку

```
serversSPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
```

Проблему решает

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zskPE1bz - код создания фрейма. Или вам нужна вся программа?

Comment: Да - нужен код создания фрейма

Comment: ... Так фрейма или программы? Код фрейма сообщением выше

Comment: Действительно, однако интересно: 100 на 100 - рандомные значения или... ???

Comment: Да - так навскидку. чтобы преферед заработал. Я много со SWINGом побился. Есть у него закидоны - особенно когда до таблиц доберешься :). Делал свою реализацию сложных заголовков.